# Tengo la siguiente lista de imagenes de un arreglo dinamico php, ¿como hago para que al clickear cualquier imagen, esta se muestre en un div?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dir="Paginas/"; 
$archivos=scandir($dir); 
$cantidad=count($archivos); 
$imagenes=array(); 
for($a="0";$a<=$cantidad;$a++) 
{ 
    if(eregi(".jpg", $archivos[$a])) 
    { 
        $imagenes[] = $archivos[$a];   
    } 
} 

$cant_imagenes=count($imagenes); 

foreach ($imagenes as $lista) 
{ 
  echo '<img id="list" src="'.$dir.''.$lista.'" ></a>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: se mas especifico!

Answer (score 0):

Un poco opaca la pregunta, pero si lo he entendido bien, lo que tu quieres es generar una galeria en la que el listado de imagenes que generas, al hacer click en alguna, muestre la imagen en todo su esplendor en otro div determinado.

Para eso, al menos en mi experiencia, te sugiero que utilices una galeria javascript como https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider para gestionarlo.
Por ejemplo, una vez colocadas las dependencias javascript, y con tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
    <ul id="light-slider">
        <?php
foreach ($imagenes as $lista) 
{
echo('<li data-thumb="'.$dir.''.$lista.'">'); 
echo('<img class="fotolistado"
                src="'.$dir.''.$lista.'"
                name="'.$dir.''.$lista.'"
                id="'.$dir.''.$lista.'"
                alt="'.$dir.''.$lista.'"
                />');
            echo('</li>');
} 
        ?>
        </ul>
```

Y despues iniciar la galeria con:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = jQuery("#light-slider").lightSlider({
        item: 1,
        autoWidth: false,
        slideMove: 1, // slidemove will be 1 if loop is true
        slideMargin: 10,
        addClass: '',
        mode: "slide",
        useCSS: true,
        cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',//
        easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',////
        speed: 500, //ms'
        auto: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        loop: true,
        slideEndAnimation: true,
        pause: 6000,
        keyPress: false,
        controls: true,
        prevHtml: '',
        nextHtml: '',
        rtl: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        vertical: false,
        verticalHeight: 500,
        vThumbWidth: 100,
        thumbItem: 6,
        pager: true,
        gallery: true,
        galleryMargin: 5,
        thumbMargin: 5,
        currentPagerPosition: 'middle',
        enableTouch: true,
        enableDrag: true,
        freeMove: true,
        swipeThreshold: 40,
        responsive: [],
        onBeforeStart: function (el) {},
        onSliderLoad: function (el) {},
        onBeforeSlide: function (el) {},
        onAfterSlide: function (el) {},
        onBeforeNextSlide: function (el) {},
        onBeforePrevSlide: function (el) {}
    });
    slider.play();
  });
```

Comment: si, he intentado con las galerías que dices, pero quería saber si lo podía hacer a partir de lo ya mostrado, agregándole una función java script. Gracias por comentar.